# Responsive Grid Div Appears in wrong position

Tags: html, grid

I'm currently making a responsive grid which is 2x2. But iv realised that at some screen sizes, the 3rd div appears below the 4th. Could somebody please tell me why its doing this?

```
 <div class="container">

        <div class="port">
            <div class="columns eight">
            <h3>Example 1</h3>
             <img src= "https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/85/209708058_b5a5fb07a6_z.jpg?zz=1"/>
               <p>Suspendisse nec elit aliquam, ultricies ex rhoncus, dapibus erat. Curabitur faucibus dui hendrerit ex laoreet, at sollicitudin nibh blandit. Suspendisse nec elit aliquam, ultricies ex rhoncus, dapibus erat. Curabitur faucibus dui hendrerit ex laoreet, at sollicitudin nibh blandit.r. Curabitur faucibus dui hendrerit ex laoreet, at sollicitudin nibh blandit.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="columns eight">
            <h3>example 2</h3>
         <img src= "https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/85/209708058_b5a5fb07a6_z.jpg?zz=1"/>
            <p>Suspendisse nec elit aliquam, ultricies ex rhoncus, dapibus erat. Curabitur faucibus dui hendrerit ex laoreet, at sollicitudin nibh blandit. Suspendisse nec elit aliquam, ultricies ex rhoncus, dapibus erat. Curabitur faucibus dui hendrerit ex laoreet, at sollicitudin nibh blandit. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="columns eight">
           <h3>Example 3</h3>
            <img src= "https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/85/209708058_b5a5fb07a6_z.jpg?zz=1"/>
            <p>Suspendisse nec elit aliquam, ultricies ex rhoncus, dapibus erat. Curabitur faucibus dui hendrerit ex laoreet, at sollicitudin nibh blandit. Suspendisse nec elit aliquam, ultricies ex rhoncus, dapibus erat. Curabitur faucibus dui hendrerit ex laoreet, at sollicitudin nibh blandit. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="columns eight">
             <h3>example 4</h3>
            <img src= "https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/85/209708058_b5a5fb07a6_z.jpg?zz=1"/>
            <p>Suspendisse nec elit aliquam, ultricies ex rhoncus, dapibus erat. Curabitur faucibus dui hendrerit ex laoreet, at sollicitudin nibh blandit. Suspendisse nec elit aliquam, ultricies ex rhoncus, dapibus erat. Curabitur faucibus dui hendrerit ex laoreet, at sollicitudin nibh blandit. </p>
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gdvwsLtt/3/

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move your following code outside of the media query so it will take action on larger screens, I believe it will behave as desired: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdvwsLtt/4/)

```
.container .port .eight:nth-child(3) {
   clear: both;
}
```